# How to deploy soap based webservice(Jax-WS) developed using java?

Tags: java, jax-ws

I am new to soap based web service.I tried and google a lot but couldn't able to find any useful resource of deploying soap based java webservice on web-logic server.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: check this 
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html

Answer (score 0):

To be able to deploy a web-service you need an application server / servlet container.

Some of the names you'd google: Jetty, Tomcat, JBoss, GlassFish

Answer (score 0):

you can deploy a service using some application server or servlet container.

Here is a good example of 
**deploying JAX-WS web services on Tomcat servlet container**
 click this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/deploy-jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat/) for more detail